# PHP Mail Not Working After Server Down

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Using:
Ubuntu 12.04.3 x64
sendmail

I set up mail using sendmail however my webhost shut my server down for an hour and afterwards my mail wasn't working. I'm not exactly sure how to isolate the problem as my knowledge is very beginner. Here is an excerpt from the mail.log before and after the server went down.

```
Mar  4 11:24:43 tossource sm-mta[6788]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar  4 11:24:44 tossource sm-mta[6788]: s24GOgGI006786: to=<example@example.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@tossource.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120862, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.25.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1393950284 u5si4372350pbi.358 - gsmtp)
Mar  4 12:34:17 tossource sm-mta[1090]: gethostbyaddr(107.170.232.249) failed: 1
Mar  4 12:34:17 tossource sm-mta[1092]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Mar  4 12:34:19 tossource sm-msp-queue[1143]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/submit.cf: line 1: invalid argument to V line: "ERSIONID(\001Id: startt"
Mar  4 12:34:19 tossource sm-msp-queue[1143]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/submit.cf: line 2: invalid argument to V line: "ERSIONID(\001Id: autoco"
```

I've been using this script to see if my PHP mail works, it doesn't.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); $to = 'your.email@address.com'; if(mail($to, 'Testing mail', 'This is a mailing test to see if PHP mail works.')) { echo 'Mail was sent by PHP'; } else { echo 'PHP could not send the mail'; } ?>
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. As I'm a beginner it would help me to have step by step instructions. Thanks.

Comment: You will probably resolve this much faster by calling your web host

Comment: I have contacted them but I'm unsure if it's their expertise as it's a VPS host.

Comment: so your web host shut down your server for an hour, it broke your sendmail, but they can't help you because they're not familiar enough with the product they sold you to assist in fixing the damage they've caused? change host immediately!!

Answer (score 0):

One of sendmail configuration files (`/etc/mail/submit.cf`) is broken.

AFAIK submit.cf is hardly ever reconfigured.

I do not know recommended fool proof way of submit.cf reinstallation from packages on Ubuntu.